# HttpContext.Current.Application during load balancing

Tags: asp.net, wcf, state

I wanted to understand the behavior of `HttpContext.Current.Application` during the load balancing.

I have read that session can be stored in disk hence can be retrieved from different servers.

Is this true for `HttpContext.Current.Application` also. Does the key\data stored in one machine is accessible in other different machine too?

Please let me know..

Thanks,
Naval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application state is not shared across web servers (ie. in a web farm) because is stored in the IIS process that contains the web application's pool.